# java - how do you write arraylist to a binary file

Tags: java, arraylist, io, binary

how do you write ArrayList into a binary file?

lets say i have a arraylist called people

i am trying to write that into a binary file using writeListToBinary method

my method:

```
public void writeListToBinary (ArrayList<Person> inList) throws IOException
```

in my main method:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
writeListToBinary(people);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to serialize your `ArrayList`. Implement `Serializable` to your class, then:

`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToSaveTo);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
out.writeObject(people)`

Also take a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: To add to this answer, an object is serializable if it implements `Serializable`, and all its non-static non-transient fields are serializable or primitives.